# check an array to not be null and get value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, redux

Learning react by coding,

in my component when it starts rendering in my console i'm getting(console.log) few times Book []
and after it i'm getting Book [{identifier: '1-1-1-1', name: 'Harry Potter'}, {identifier: '2-4-6-1', name: 'Narnia'}]

So first renders array has nothing in it, is there a way to check when array has something in it then go and take first identifier you find(then i will dispatch it) ?

any suggestions ?

my unsuccessful code:

```js
        const books = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.library.books);
        console.log("books", books.length > 0 && books[0]?.identifier)
  
        dispatch(bookIdentifier("here i need to dispatch first identifier from list"));
```

Comment: can you provide minimal comlpete piece of code to understand the context?

Comment: that console log (books.length > 0 && books[0]?.identifier)  it gives me:  5 books false   then after that i'm getting values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
const books = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.library.books);

useEffect(() => {
    if (books?.length > 0 && books?.[0]?.identifier) dispatch(bookIdentifier(books[0].identifier));
}, [books])
```

Comment: i edited your useEffect a little then it worked, here : useEffect(() => {
    if (books.length > 0 ) dispatch(bookIdentifier(books[0]?.identifier));
}, [books])

Comment: should i accept your anwer or write an answer that what i changed from your code and got it working ?

Comment: Oh, it's up to you, both answers is similar

Comment: @walee I've edit question, added [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to make sure it not errors if books is not an array

Comment: what if i put optional chaining inside bookIdentifier : useEffect(() => { if (books.length > 0 ) dispatch(bookIdentifier(books?.[0]?.identifier)); }, [books])    does it mean the same thing ?

Comment: so if somehow books is a string, so books.length is true and books?.[0]?.identifier will be undefined. So you dispatch bookIdentifier as undefined

Comment: could you possibly also anwer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158201/react-broken-state-from-drawimage