# React broken state from drawImage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

React beginner here, I'm getting this error 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.'
i have been stuck with this for few hours now.

That error is showing on drawImage which is inside if statement.
Is there a way to tell it if there is an image then go on and draw it (          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)), but if there isnt any image then dont give any error(dont show any image either), something like what Optional chaining (?.) does ?

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

my code:

```js
 
     const CameraCanvas = useRef<any>();
     const CameraImage = useRef<any>();
 
  const updatePreviewUrl = () => {
  if (currentCam) {
  let curSnapshotUrl = state.snapshot?.snapshotUrl.split("?ts=")[0];
  let newSnapshotUrl =
    `api/cam/${....}/` +
    `${curCam.ident}/snapsht`;
  if (curSnapshotUrl ....) {
    setState({
    ...
    });
  }
}
  };

    const updateCanvas = () => {
    updatePreviewUrl();
    const canvas = CameraCanvas.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const img = CameraImage.current;
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    if (currentCam) {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
    }
  };
 
 
 useEffect(() => {
        updateCanvas();
        const img = CameraImage.current;
        img.onload = updateCanvas;

        return () => {
          img.onload = null;
        };
      });
```

Comment: Any idea or help is appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure the image is loading correctly? Are there any console errors?

Comment: @BankBuilder image is loading correctly, but when i change image (images chosen by clicking buttons) then i get that error

Comment: @walee what is currentCam? can you show full code?

Comment: I might have found the issue. Try removing `updateCanvas()` from the top of `useEffect()`. You need this to be called only after the img loads (which you accomplish two lines down). Comment that line and it may work without error.

Comment: @iamhuynq i have buttons, each button when clicked activates camera and that currentCam is currently clicked button

Comment: @BankBuilder i have buttons, each button when clicked activates camera and that currentCam is currently clicked button, i need that updateCanvas to be there at top of that useEffect otherwise clicking button wont activate cameras

Comment: We need to see where `CameraImage` is actually set.